# I've renamed project directories on IntelliJ, and now, each launching, it recreates empty directories with the old names and an .iml file inside

Tags: intellij-idea, project-structure

I've shortened my projects directories names,
using `F6 = Refactor → Rename → Directory Name`:
`Application → App`

It worked, but now, each time I'm restarting *IntelliJ 2023.3.1*, it recreates on disk, and lists in the project window, old directories names among with the renamed ones.

The old directories recreated contain only an `.iml` file

Destroying them have no effect: they disappear, but they are recreated at the next launching.

[image]

Everything is working well, else.
And a `Find in Files` doesn't mention old directories names anywhere.

I don't understand where they are coming from.

- `F4 - Project Structure` works on renamed directories
- but not on these recreated old directories, because they aren't really a part of my project

so I have no clue about them.

Running the five steps of Repair IDE after having deleted them have no effect : they are still recreated at the next launching.

I would like to get rid of these recreated old directories.

Answer (score 1):

I write the current workaround I've found:

it's to close *IntelliJ*, delete the hidden `.idea` folder at the parent folder of the project, and restart it.

It works, at the cost of loosing all your compilation and project settings.

Comment: It sounds like either a caching or project configuration corruption issue. Re-generating the project (or subproject) configuration (= deleting the .idea folder) is the the correct first step in troubleshooting such issues. If it happens again, see if it helps to disable all of the non-bundled plugins and restart the IDE: 'Preferences | Plugins | ⚙ | Disable all downloaded plugins'